# how can i add a regular item to spinner adapter?

Tags: android

i have a spinner like this:

```
spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spin);
        _spinDb = new SpinAdapter(this);
        Cursor names = _spinDb.open().getAllSpin();
        _adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                names,
                new String[] {SpinAdapter.COLUMN_NAME},
                new int[] {android.R.id.text1});
_adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(_adapter);
```

now, i want to add a "regular" item with the text: "choose item". how can i do it?
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add your first element of the string[] array. Then be sure if position not 0 (zero) do others.

Comment: how do i do this? i tried new String[] {"Choose item", SpinAdapter.COLUMN_NAME} and it didn't work...

Comment: Get Clumn_name first and insert the Choose İtem element in the first element of the list. Than, create a new string array and copy the list to it. Then use the new array for the spinner source.

Answer (score 0):

Note: The constructor you are trying to use has been deprecated.

I don't think you should try to use a SimpleCursorAdapter if you are just going to need to hack in a row that is not in the database.  You are probably better off just trying to use a SimpleAdapter and populating it separately. (You could also simply add in "Choose item" into your database if you wish).